# Java Jersey not sending ssl client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have Jersey app which uses Jersey client to request a server. Server uses client certificate and basic auth to communicate. I have setup truststore and keystore properly with certificates in glassfish

Server certificate chain: 
Server cert -> CA Inter -> CA

client certificate chain: 
client cert -> CA Inter -> CA

CA is self created/signed certificate and not from a vendor.

truststore:

1) CA

2) CA Inter

keystore:

1) client certificate with complete chain

Code: (stores are set in environment)

```
sSLContext = SslConfigurator.newInstance().securityProtocol("TLSv1.2").createSSLContext();
HttpAuthenticationFeature authFeature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("user", "pass");
client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sSLContext).build();
client.register(authFeature);
```

All certificates and chains are loaded properly.

However when i make a request i get

```
Info:   Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
```

and then i get handshake_failure error

I get these other errors

```
Info:   http-listener-1(3), setSoTimeout(0) called
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Info:   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
```

I have installed unlimited chiper extension and checked that its working. Still getting these.

I have also checked certificate on browser and i am able to connect to server via browser and fetch data using same certificates.

How to get 2-way ssl to work?

Answer (score 0):

Both client and sever need the CA certificate in their respective truststores. I would say the server doesn't.

When the server requests the client certificate, it sends its list of trusted CAs, and if the client can't find a certificate signed by one of them it doesn't send one,

Comment: I have two keystores cacerts.jks and keystore.jks, what will be client's truststore? I have CA and CA inter in both server and client Chain and they match. I have ca-certs.pem as cert chain set in apache server. That contain CA cert. And i have verified that server cert request type matches one present in client